# Using templated struct as constructor argument

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, metaprogramming

I have a template class Point which will store x and y coordinates, data type of both can be any arithmetic type.

```
template <typename T, typename U>
struct Point {
  T x;
  U y;
};
```

Line class takes two Points as constructor argument to find equation of line.

```
class Line {
public:
  Line(Point p1, Point p2) {}
};
```

How can I design Line class so it can accept Point object of different data types?

I have designed something like below, how can I improve it?

```
template <class T, class U,
          class = typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value &&
                                          std::is_arithmetic<U>::value>::type>
struct Point
{
    T x;
    U y;
    typedef T x_type;
    typedef U y_type;
};

template <typename T1, 
          typename T2,
          typename P1 = typename T1::x_type,
          typename P2 = typename T1::y_type,
          typename P3 = typename T2::x_type,
          typename P4 = typename T2::y_type>
class Line {
public:
  Line(Point<P1, P2> p1, Point<P3, P4> p2) {}
};
```

The way I am planning to use is:

```
Point<int, long> p1 (2, 5);
Point<short, double> p2 (77, 33.5);
Line<Point<int, long>, Point<short, double>> line_(p1, p2);

OR

Line<Point<int, short>, Point<float, unsigned>> eq({1, 1}, {2.3f, 2});
```

What are the ways to to improvise or shorten the code.

Comment: Show how the `template class Line` is currently used, and indicate what specifically you want to improve. Do you feel you're being required to specify seemingly redundant template arguments upon instantiation? or what?

Comment: What about `template<class P> class Line { P _p1; P _p2; public: Line(P p1, P p2) : _p1(p1), _p2(p2) {} };`?

Comment: Note: Add perfect forwarding on your own discretion.

Comment: @underscore_d I am planning to use it in following way Point<int, long> p1; Point<short, double> p2; Line line_(p1, p2); OR Line <Point<int, long>, Point<short, double>> line;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to have so many type parameters in `Line`.

```
template <typename Point> 
struct is_point : std::false_type {};

template <typename T, typename U>
struct is_point<Point<T, U>> : std::true_type {};

template <typename P1, typename P2>
class Line {
   static_assert(is_point<P1>::value && is_point<P2>::value, "Line needs Point template parameters")
   public:
   Line(P1 p1, P2 p2) {}
};
```

Comment: Thanks, very crisp and easy to understand code. Could you guide me to few books or docs which I can refer to understand templates to write such code.

Comment: Point members need only to be arithmetic type, so should I put is_aritmetic check in struct Point or in trait is_point? Which will be proper?

Comment: @Daemon I'd keep it in `Point`, although I'd express it as a similar `static_assert`

Answer (score 2):

Templates are just templates, not types. You cannot have a function that takes a template as parameter, unless you write a function template, or in case of your `Line` a class template as you already have, but it can be written a bit simpler:

```
template <typename T,typename U>
class Line {       
   public:
   Line(Point<T,U> p1,Point<T,U> p2) {}
};
```

Alternatively parametrize `Line` on the type of the points:

```
template <typename P>
class Line {       
   public:
   Line(P p1,P p2) {}
};
```

> How can I design Line class so it can accept Point object of different data types?

Note that the template `Line` accepts different types of `Point`s, but one particular instantiation eg `Line<int,int>` will only accept `Point<int,int>` and it is a type completely different and having no relation to eg `Line<int,double>`. If you want to have one type of lines that accepts different points, more is needed. It really depends on what you actually want to achieve.

Comment: There are other options, e.g. the `class` could be templated on `template <typename, typename> T, template <typename, typename> U`, and/or could use `x_type` and `y_type` in the constructor argument list (better via `using` declarations) rather than redundantly being templated on those too, and with C++20 one could use concepts to get really specific with what would be allowed, and so on. But it's not at all clear what the OP currently considers suboptimal about however this currently ends up looking at sites where it's used.

Comment: @underscore_d the solution OP has is clearly not nice and I have the feeling that they just didnt know which way to go, so I just provided alternatives. Though, I agree that the quesiton could be more clear

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 The first option you provided will not allow me to have Point object of all different data types i.e I cannot mix <int, short>, <double, long>. The second solution provided I am not clear how can I use it, it looks like its templated on one parameter, it does not clarify that P is Point. I might be wrong, please clarify.

Comment: @Daemon for first part of your comment: at the time of writing this answer your requirements were not quite clear. If you want full flexibility, just add template parameters `V` and `W` to allow the two points to be of different type. For the second part: the template does not need to know what type `P` actually is. Only when you instantiate it via `Line<Point<int,int>>` you have to choose. And same here: For more flexibility you can add a second parameter `P2` to allow two different types of points. Maybe I will update the answer, just dont have the time atm